# addImageToMediaGallery copy the image file to media folder

Tags: product, magento-1, import, image

I use addImageToMediaGallery to add images for products. Images are associated correctly but I've problem, the final path become /media/catalog/product, etc etc. I've tried with

```
$product->addImageToMediaGallery($imgPath, null , false , false);
```

or

```
$product->addImageToMediaGallery($imgPath, null , true , false);
```

the result is the same.

How to add an image with a specific path?

Thanks for all.

Comment: What path do you want it to be?

Answer (score 8):

Setting the third perimeter of `$product->addImageToMediaGallery` to true/false doesn't seem to have any effect on the storage destination of the file itself, it just changes the operation it uses (copy/mod vs move command) to get it into the correct Magento image directory structure.

Also, I don`t think it is possible to choose a specific image path without a lot of customization. By default Magento store image in the following format /media/catalog/product/{a}/{b} where 'a' and 'be are the first two letters of the image file name.

See

> /app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product.php

```
/**
 * Add image to the media gallery
 *
 * @param string        $file path of the image in the file system
 * @param string|array  $mediaAttribute    code of attribute with type 'media_image',
 *                                          leave blank if the image should be only in a gallery
 * @param boolean       $move              if true, it will move the source file
 * @param boolean       $exclude           mark image as disabled in product page view
 * @return Mage_Catalog_Model_Product
 */
public function addImageToMediaGallery($file, $mediaAttribute=null, $move=false, $exclude=true)
{
    .....
    /* @var $mediaGalleryAttribute Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute */
    $mediaGalleryAttribute->getBackend()->addImage($this, $file, $mediaAttribute, $move, $exclude);
    return $this;
}
```

> /app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Attribute/Backend/Media.php

```
/**
 * Add image to media gallery and return new filename
 *
 * @param Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product
 * @param string                     $file path of image in file system
 * @param string|array               $mediaAttribute    code of attribute with type 'media_image',
 *                                                      leave blank if image should be only in gallery
 * @param boolean                    $move              if true, it will move source file
 * @param boolean                    $exclude           mark image as disabled in product page view
 * @return string
 */
public function addImage(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product, $file,
    $mediaAttribute = null, $move = false, $exclude = true)
{
  ....
        /** @var $storageHelper Mage_Core_Helper_File_Storage_Database */
        $storageHelper = Mage::helper('core/file_storage_database');
        if ($move) {
            $ioAdapter->mv($file, $this->_getConfig()->getTmpMediaPath($fileName));

            //If this is used, filesystem should be configured properly
            $storageHelper->saveFile($this->_getConfig()->getTmpMediaShortUrl($fileName));
        } else {
            $ioAdapter->cp($file, $this->_getConfig()->getTmpMediaPath($fileName));

            $storageHelper->saveFile($this->_getConfig()->getTmpMediaShortUrl($fileName));
            $ioAdapter->chmod($this->_getConfig()->getTmpMediaPath($fileName), 0777);
        }
```