# Programmatically adding images to products

Tags: product, magento-1, product-images, programmatically

I am trying to create a system which automatically creates a configurable product and creates and associates simple products to it.
It is all working well but a lot of the simple products will be using the same images, by using the following code :

```
$product->addImageToMediaGallery('/var/www/test.jpg', $mediaAttribute, false, false);
```

It duplicates the image which is not what I wanted so I tried to do it this way:

```
$mediaGalleryData['images'][] =   array(
        'file'     => 'filepath here located in media/catalog dir',
        'position' => 0,
        'label'    => 'label',
        'disabled' => 0
    );

    $product->setData($attrCode, $mediaGalleryData);
    $product->save();
```

This does add an image to the product but somehow the filepath is changed to the one I provide extended by '_1', resulting into referring to a non existent file..

Is there any way to do this without getting the automatically asigned '_1' at the end of the file path?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to take a look at `/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Attribute/Backend/Media.php`

- https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/cb52550f2aa31026dfa9cb95709c567ebe3fded7/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Attribute/Backend/Media.php#L434

Also, the easiest approach is using the API models to remove the image before reimporting:

```
Mage::app()->getStore()->setId(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
if ($product->getId()){
    $mediaApi = Mage::getModel("catalog/product_attribute_media_api");
    $items = $mediaApi->items($product->getId());
    foreach($items as $item)
        $mediaApi->remove($product->getId(), $item['file']);
}
```

Some related:

- [addImageToMediaGallery copy the image file to media folder](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/37564/addimagetomediagallery-copy-the-image-file-to-media-folder)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5709496/magento-programmatically-remove-product-images
- https://github.com/avstudnitz/AvS_FastSimpleImport