# Upload Image Magento API

Tags: magento-1.9, soap, image-upload

I'm creating a SOAP v2 api in Magento, and one of the methods is to upload an image to the Magento media folder.
So my question is: how can I send an image to magento without using a form? and how can I upload it to the media folder.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is place images to media/import folder before and then use

```
$product->addImageToMediaGallery($filePath, array ('image','small_image','thumbnail'), false, false);
```

function.

Check this comment for the full description of this function [addImageToMediaGallery copy the image file to media folder](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/37564/addimagetomediagallery-copy-the-image-file-to-media-folder)

If you can't upload images, you can use two ways:

1. Send images to API as strings and on your side use file_put_contents to save it
2. Send images to API as links and on your side use file_get_contents/file_put_contents to get/save them

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I can't put the images before because I don't know which image you're going to upload, so  I need to create a method that receives per parameters an image ,s o the method will store this image into Magento

Comment: I update my answer

Comment: Thanks, this is my code:
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
$api_url = "http://local/index.php/api/v2_soap/?wsdl=1"; //For Version 2
$username = 'test';
$password = 'test123';
$client = new SoapClient($api_url,array('cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE));  //Will cnot cache the WSDL
//retreive session id from login
$session = $client->login($username, $password);

$image= '/home/proximitycr/Desktop/hey.jpg';

$result = $client->loadImageToGallery($session,$image);

var_dump($result);

Comment: and I Need the method loadImageToGallery

Comment: In method loadImageToGallery you pass argument - URL to your image. Use file_get_contents to get this image as string and then file_put_contents to save it to media/import. After that, use Magento function addImageToMediaGallery with URL to your file in media/import.

Answer (score 0):

```
 //get the form data 
 $data = $this->getRequest()->getData(); 
 $sku = $data['sku'];
 //get other product attributes and add like below
 the following is the api that you will call
 try {
                $result = $client->call($session, 'catalog_product.create', array('simple', $attributeSet['set_id'], $sku, array(
                        'categories' => array($categories),
                        'websites' => array($websites),
                        'name' => $name,
                        'description' => $description,
                        'short_description' => $short_description,
                        'weight' => $weight,
                        'status' => $status,
                        'url_key' => str_replace(' ', '_', $url_key),
                        'url_path' => str_replace(' ', '_', $url_key),
                        'visibility' => $visibility,
                        'price' => $price,
                        'tax_class_id' => $tax_class,
                        'meta_title' => $meta_title,
                        'meta_keyword' => $meta_keyword,
                        'meta_description' => $meta_description,
                        'front_image' => $image
                )));
            } catch (SoapFault $fault) {
                Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError($fault->getMessage());
                header('Location: ' . Mage::getBaseUrl() . 'product');
                exit;
            }

            $productId = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getIdBySku($sku);
            $
```

if you see in the end you have

> `$productId`

you can add images to products using the following code

```
        if (!file_exists($imageResized) && file_exists($imagePath)) {
            $imageObj = new Varien_Image($imagePath);
            $imageObj->constrainOnly(TRUE);
            $imageObj->keepAspectRatio(TRUE);
            $imageObj->keepFrame(FALSE);
            $imageObj->resize(600);
            $imageObj->save($imageResized);

            $product->setMediaGallery(array('images' => array(), 'values' => array()));
            $product->addImageToMediaGallery($imageResized, array('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail'), false, false);
            $product->addImageToMediaGallery
            $product->save();
        }
```

The idea is this: You are creating the product first then you are adding the images directly after creating the product.

Hope you got the idea. 
Thanks